# Load multiple multischema delimited file from same directories

Tags: talend

Could I know does it have any method to load multiple files that are multi schema delimited files which store in same directories in Talend?

I have tried use the tFileInputMSDelimited component before, but unable to link with tFilelist component to loop through the files inside the directory.

Does anyone have idea how to solve this problem?

To make clearer, each file only contain one batch line but contain multiple header line and it comes with a bunch of transaction line. As showing at the sample data below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello wz, can you post ascreenshot of your job so far ?

Comment: Hi, Carassus, this is how far I done and could you have any idea combine it back to multischema delimited file again?

Comment: Thanks. 
What are the names of the files ?
And what is the mask used in the tFileList ?

Comment: All the filename consist of FFA, so just use it *FFA* as mask.

Comment: And one constant is all transaction header is I, Headerline header is H and Batch header is some “0000135A” something like this, do you think possible to generate a sequence then combine it back to Multi schema output?

Comment: Okay I tried something on my end and it seems to work OK. I will post a full answer later =)

Comment: Sure, Thanks first.

Comment: Could I see your solution?

Comment: Sorry, busy day, I will post it a bit later. =/

Answer (score 1):

The component tFileOutputMSDelimited should suit your needs.

You will need multiple flows going into it.
You can either keep the files and read them or use tHashInput/tHashOutput to get the data directly.

Then you direct all the flows to the tFileOutputMSDelimited (example with tFixedFlowInput, adapt with your flows) :

[image: Example with tFixedFlowInput]

In it, you can configure which flow is the parent flow containing your ID.
Then you can add the children flows and define the parent and the ID to recognize the rows in the parent flow :

[image: tFileOutputMSDelimited config]

Comment: First of all, Thanks Carassus, but because the Talend big data edition that I use don't have Hashinput/Hashoutput components, so how to use the fixedflowinput to pass to the files into the fixedflowinput and go to the OutputMsDelimited? and how could I define parent key in my case?

Comment: @Wz98, the tHashInput/tHashOutput components are considered "too technical" by Talend team (they're really not) so they are a bit hidden. You must activate them yourself in the palette settings : https://help.talend.com/reader/iDUwyneSPUgZVyVcWpVlVw/v0SoaRheiWnba9aPAp21gQ